# How can I get the selected code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

For my plugin I'm trying to access the selected code in a CompilationUnitEditor. Therefore I added a contribution to the context menu and use following code:

```
public class ContextMenuHandler implements IEditorActionDelegate {

    private IEditorPart editorPart;

    @Override
    public void setActiveEditor(IAction action, IEditorPart editorPart) {
        this.editorPart = editorPart;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(IAction action) {
        JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editorPart.getEditorInput());
    }

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
        if (selection instanceof TextSelection) {
            TextSelection text = (TextSelection) selection;
            System.out.println("Text: " + text.getText());
        } else {
            System.out.println(selection);
        }
    }

}
```

Now the problem is that the method selectionChanged(...) is only called when i really select something so that I could copy/paste it. But I want to access the Code elements that are highlighted like this (here I would like to get the "IEditorPart")

[image]

Unfortunately, I have no idea what I should look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inputs from the other answers, I ended up with the following solution:

```
@Override
public void setActiveEditor(IAction action, IEditorPart editorPart) {
    ((CompilationUnitEditor) editorPart).getViewer().addTextListener(new ITextListener() {

        @Override
        public void textChanged(TextEvent event) {
            selectedText = event.getText();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should do this:

```
        ((CompilationUnitEditor) editorPart).getViewer().getSelectedRange();
```

The `ISourceViewer` class has quite a few useful and interesting methods regarding source locations and the editor.  You may also want to look at `JavaSourceViewer`.

---

EDIT

It looks like I didn't quite answer your question.  The problem is that selectionChanged events are only called when the length of the selection is > 0.  I don't know why this is the case, but that is the way action delegates have always worked.

If you want to be notified whenever the caret changes, you should register a selection changed listener with the viewer for the editor.  Do something like this:

```
((CompilationUnitEditor) editorPart).getViewer()
  .addSelectionChangedListener(mySelectionListener);
```

`mySelectionListener` is of type `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener`.  Registering in this way, should give you all the events you are looking for.  Just be careful to unregister when the editor closes.

Comment: Then i get back a Point. What should I do with that?

Comment: if you read the JavaDoc, you will see: "Returns the range of the current selection in coordinates of this viewer's document.

Returns:
a Point with x as the offset and y as the length of the current selection"

Comment: Actually, re-reading you question and I am no longer sure what you are looking for.  Do you want the selected range?  Do you want the Java element that contains the selected text?  Or do you want to resolve the thing that is currently selected to determine its declaration?

Comment: I think he wants to retrieve the word, or Java identifier under the caret, but there is not really a text which is selected. I assumed also that he wanted a event fired on such a change (ala `selectionChanged()`), this is why I proposed the `CaretListener`.

Comment: In my Eclipse i can highlight types and methods like that. Then I can press F2 to get the documentation. Now I want to register a listener for this events. And I want only the word. That's enough for me.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg but the class CompilationUnitEditor has no method getSourceViewer?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg using Reflection I achieved to add a Listener, but it is still not the solution. It contains only the selection when I use the mouse to select a couple of characters.

Comment: Right...getSourceViewer is protected.  You should use getViewer instead.  Apologies.  This is working for me.  Set a breakpoint in the method org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent) and then change selection in the editor.  You'll see that it gets called every time the selection changes.  If you call addSelectionChangedListener on the viewer, then your listener will be called when you need it to.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get my solution working with your help. That's why I'm giving you the bounty and I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to detect the caret current position. Having the position let you easily detect if the caret is on a word (define word as you like, for example space-separated, java identifier, or with a regular expression).

I'm not able to run eclipse here, but I would use the [CaretListener](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CaretListener.html) class in order to detect caret movements and thus extracting the word under it. The `CaretEvent` given as parameter to the `caretMoved` method will contain the offset.

The `CaretListener` can be attached to the `Adapter` of your `StyledText` component, that you can get from your `EditorPart` (don't have any more info for the moment, as I don't have eclipse running here).

Hope it helps.

Edit: Some code.

```
final StyledText text = (StyledText)editorPart.getAdapter(Control.class);
text.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
        public void caretMoved(CaretEvent event) {
            int offset = event.caretOffset;
            String word = findWord(offset, text);
            if (word.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Word under caret: " + word);
            }
        }
});

private String findWord(int offset, StyledText text) {
    int lineIndex = text.getLineAtOffset(offset);
    int offsetInLine = offset - text.getOffsetAtLine(lineIndex);
    String line = text.getLine(lineIndex);
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    if (offsetInLine > 0 && offsetInLine < line.length()) {
        for (int i = offsetInLine; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (!Character.isSpaceChar(line.charAt(i))) {
                word.append(line.charAt(i));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        word = word.reverse();
    }
    if (offsetInLine < line.length()) {
        for (int i = offsetInLine; i < line.length(); ++i) {
            if (i == offsetInLine)
                continue; // duplicate
            if (!Character.isSpaceChar(line.charAt(i))) {
                word.append(line.charAt(i));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return word.toString();
}
```

This is simple implementation to get the word under the cursor based on space character surrounding it. A more robust implementation should be used in order to detect valid Java identifiers etc. For example using `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart` and `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart` or using a library for this.

Comment: That would work I think, however I strongly assume that there has to be a better option.

Comment: This might work, but I would recommend against this solution since doing so would be accessing a very low-level API.  You should be interacting with the editor via JFace APIs such as the source viewer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test that right now. However to get it working the variable text has to be final. I edited that in your answer.